# Immutable objects and unmodifiable collections

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections, immutability

With an immutable object, where is it proper to wrap a contained collection as unmodifiable?  I see 3 options:

1. In the immutable object's factory:

   ```
   public class ImmutableFactory {

       public Immutable build(){
          List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

           values.add(1);
           values.add(2);
           values.add(3);

           return new Immutable(Collections.unmodifiableList(values), "hello");
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the immutable's contructor

   ```
   public class Immutable {

       private final List<Integer> values;
       private final String hello;

       public Immutable(List<Integer> values, String hello) {
           this.values = Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
          this.hello = hello;
       }

       public List<Integer> getValues() {
           return values;
       }

       public String getHello() {
           return hello;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the immutable's accessor (if applicable).

   ```
   public class Immutable {

       private final List<Integer> values;
       private final String hello;

       public Immutable(List<Integer> values, String hello) {
           this.values = values;
           this.hello = hello;
       }

       public List<Integer> getValues() {
           return Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
       }

       public String getHello() {
           return hello;
       }
   }
   ```

Are there any other options and which one is proper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say if you create Immutable collection then you need to protect yourself from somebody modifying list that was given as an argument to constructor, you should protectively copy it.

```
public Immutable(List<Integer> values, String hello) {
    this.values = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Integer>(values));
    this.hello = hello;
}
```

I personally have long ago switched to [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) collections as there you can find interfaces for immutable collections. Your constructor would look like that:

```
public Immutable(ImmutableList<Integer> values, String hello) {
    this.values = values;
    this.hello = hello;
}
```

You'd be sure that argument you receive will not be modified by anyone.

It is usually a good idea to keep reference to immutable list within your immutable class as it then guarantees that you don't modify it by mistake.

Case (1) in my opinion makes sense only when factory method is the only way to create the immutable collection and even then it may break when someone refactors these classes. Unless there are other limitations it is always best to create self-sufficient classes.

Comment: Great points.  I'm going to give guava a shot since I've been focusing on immutability.

Comment: if you had a getter that returns your collection 'values' would you return a type of List or ImmutableList?

Comment: I'd just return `List`.  (That said, Guava is smart about that -- if you call `ImmutableList.copyOf` defensively on a list that's already immutable, it won't actually do the copy, except in cases where that would cause memory leaks.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Great to hear from Guava team member! Thank you for such an outstanding library! Out of general interest, could you please point me to a page where I could read about those edge cases that may lead to memory leaks?

Comment: Not really?  Mostly it's just the obvious cases -- e.g. if you have a `hugeList.subList(0, 10)`, you want to explicitly copy that, because `hugeList` might be holding onto hundreds of thousands of elements you don't need.  It's just the dumb cases like that.  Probably the most general discussion of what `copyOf` does is [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained#copyOf_is_smarter_than_you_think).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code in all places is indeed immutable **but** only because an `Integer` is immutable.
If you had `private final List<SomeCustomClass> values;` instead, `Collections.unmodifiableList(values);` would not guarantee that individual `SomeCustomClass` of the list is immutable. *You* would have to code for that.
Having said that, another option is to do a **defencive deep copy** of the list. This approach also offers immutability.

Comment: A `List<someClassType>` does not *hold* class-type items; it *identifies* them.  If a `List<someClassType>` is made unmodifiable, it will always identify the same items.  If one has a printed list of ten cars which happen to be red, painting one of the cars blue would not change the list.  The list would still identify the same ten cars.  Likewise, the state of a `List<someClassType>` does not encapsulate the state of the items thereon, but merely their identity.  If one is holding a list of private objects whose state one is interested in, and one wants to give someone a list...

Comment: ...of objects whose states represent snapshots of those on the first list, one must new objects as snapshots of those in the first list, and generate a new list which identifies those new objects.  It's too bad neither Java nor any .net languages allow one to specify that an object reference is held for the purpose of encapsulating the state of a private mutable object.  The fact that there's no distinction made between variables which encapsulate unshared mutable state, identity, both, or neither, is to my mind a weakness rather than a strength.